# List view SubItem convert Int to view Numeric numbers

Tags: vb.net, listview

```
Dim rcc As String

Try       
    rcc = saaoblv.SelectedItems(0).Text
    strSQL = "SELECT * from budget  where ctrl = '" & rcc & "' and types = 'MOOE'"
    CONNECTION.Open()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, CONNECTION)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    MOOElv.Items.Clear()

    Do While dr.Read()

        Dim lv As New ListViewItem(dr("Particular").ToString())
        lv.SubItems.Add(dr("Ep").ToString())
        lv.SubItems.Add(CInt(dr("Allotment")).ToString("#,##0.00"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(CInt(dr("Obligation")).ToString("#,##0.00"))
        lv.SubItems.Add(dr("Balance").ToString())

        MOOElv.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {lv})

    Loop
    dr.Close()
    CONNECTION.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MOOElv.Clear()
End Try

lv.SubItems.Add(CInt(dr("Allotment")).ToString("#,##0.00"))
lv.SubItems.Add(CInt(dr("Obligation")).ToString("#,##0.00"))
```

I want to display the Allotment, Obligation and Balance as Currency or Numeric in the ListView, but only one column works. If I convert the other ones as above, it will make my ListView blank.

Comment: If your `ListView` is blank then that is presumably because an exception is being thrown, as you're calling `Clear` in the `Catch` block.  Perhaps you should find out what that exception is, so you can look at fixing the cause.

Comment: thanks :D for the idea